# Adding a class or ID to php file

Tags: css, stylesheet

How can I add an additional class to this php code?

```
<form action="<?php echo CRoute::getURI(); ?>" method="post" id="jomsForm" name="jomsForm" class="community-form-validate">
```

I'm guessing it should be like this right?

```
<form action="<?php echo CRoute::getURI(); ?>" method="post" id="jomsForm" name="jomsForm" class="community-form-validate newclass">
```

I tried adding a style on my stylesheet

```
.newclass{
    margin-top:200px
}
```

but its not working, am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: css given for the class is not getting applied to the form.. is this your problem?? if so this may be due to the missed ";" in your css. your css should be like this `margin-top:200px;`

Comment: instead of giving top margin to form try by giving top-margin to first child element...

Comment: form is not a layout tag. Apply the margin to its immediate parent.

Answer (score 0):

and with this instead ?

```
.newclass
{
    display: block!important;
    margin-top: 200px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with you CSS selection in this case. Also remember to add the semi-colon.

```
form.newclass {
    margin-top:200px;
}
```